# Scan Vs BatchGetItems in Dynamo-db

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

If I know the primary key of the items, Which approach is best approach

- Scan with FilterExpression with IN Operator
- BatchGetItem with  all keys in request parameter

Please recommend the solution in terms of both latency and partitions impact.

Answer (score 2):

Probably neither. Of course it all depends on the key schema and the data in the table, but you probably want to create an Global Secondary Index for your most frequently used queries.

Having said that; performing scans is highly discouraged, especially when working with large volumes of data. So if you know the primary key of the items you're interested in, go for `BatchGetItems` over doing a scan.